# Copying the value of each row pasting into another new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

the main thing is i would like to get each value of 'lot_size' of 'size' and paste it into a new column called as "lot_size_r". But my code only takes the latest value and pastes the same value to each row.
Here is my table;
[image: main-table]

And i tried to copy every value into an empty array, then add it to a new column (which need to be 'lot_size_r') but i still get an array filled with the latest value of 'lot_size' 'size' keys' value. 
[image: sizearr]

I also tried directly append it into the DataFrame but as you can see, it pushes only one and same value... 
[image: main-problem]

I hope i could state the problem clear, for ex. there will be a new column called as 'lot_size_r' and filled with the 'lot_size' 's 'size' value...
shortly, i would like to append these values into a new column;
[image: values]

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the dictionary value into another row.
You can use `.str` to access the content and get the key.

```
df['lot_size_r'] = df['lot_size'].str['size']
```

PS. Don't post code pictures as it's difficult to reporoduce.